# Double integration problem, how to integrate $e^{x^2}$?

Tags: integration

What is the value of $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^ye^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)}dxdy$$ I draw the region of integration tried to change the order but still i don't know how to integrate $e^{x^2}$

Comment: Hint: polar coordinates

Comment: if the internal integral runs to $y$ and not $\infty$ you are in trouble. The dreaded erf function will come and bite you.

Comment: Do you know the Normal distribution? Note that you have to integrate $e^{\mathbf{-}x^2}$, not $e^{x^2}$, which is not integrable on $( - \infty , y]$.

Comment: Do you know function **erf(.)** ?

Comment: @Kraxxus Actually, no, since, by symmetry, $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^ye^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)}dxdy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)}dxdy$$ hence the *dreaded function* will bite nobody here.

Comment: @Hetebrij I do know Normal distribution and if I am not wrong then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx$ will be equal to 1 but how to use this in the context.

Comment: $e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)} = e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}} e^{ -\frac{y^2}{2}}$, and then use, but still proof it yourself, the symmetry Did proposed to split the double integral into a product of two single integrals which you can solve.

Answer (score 2):

Of course, they are several methods to solve the double integral. Among them, using polar coordinates is one of the easiest :
 $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^ye^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)}dxdy=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}r dr d\theta$$
$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}}r dr =-\left[e^{-\frac{r^2}{2}} \right]_0^\infty=1\:\:$ and $\:\:\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}d\theta=\pi$
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^ye^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x^2+y^2\right)}dxdy=\frac{1}{2\pi}\pi=\frac{1}{2}$$
The area of integration is made obvious below :

(in Cartesian coordinates, $\:x\:$ varies from $\:-\infty\:$ to $\:x=y\:$, so the area of integration is all the left side of the line $\:y=x\:$ ).

[image]

Comment: Thanks @J Jacquelin sometimes my brain doesn't work properly, I use polar coordinates very often specially in case where $x^2+y^2$ are there in the question.